# How to Distinguish Between Energy and Coenergy in an Electric Field

Tags: calculus, integration, vector-fields, electromagnetism

I am perusing through my principles of electromechanics textbook and was puzzled by how the electric field energy equation was formulated. For example, the Electric field energy for a capacitor is defined by the integral of voltage (lambda dot in the attachment) as a function of charge (the prime symbol indicates that the charge is also a function of time but the charge coordinate is used instead). If you reverse the placement of voltage and charge in the equation, you obtain coenergy, which isn't a physically significant value, but is useful for evaluating energy when the units are more convenient. However, that does not explain why the order matters, but I did think about it. I listed my thought process below:

The main differential equation for a capacitor is $I = C{dV\over dt}$, where I=current and V=voltage. If you take the integral of each side with respect to time,
you obtain, ${1\over C}\int dt=V$. If you take the integral of current with respect to time, you obtain charge q if current is constant over time and since voltage is the dependent variable and charge is the independent variable, energy is a product of the changing charge, not the changing voltage, since it is the charges themselves that create the electric field. That is my reasoning, but I don't know if I am close or really far off.

I posted all relevant attachments that I could think of below. I would be very grateful for your help. Thank you plenty!

Best, 
Truth_Seeker24

[Electric Field Energy Equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaylW.jpg)

[Energy/Coenergy Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvAmh.jpg)

Comment: I'm not certain exactly what your question is, but your explanation sounds good. I would think of it as I = C(dV/dt) and current is the change in charge over change in time, so we have (dq/dt) = C(dV/dt), then just cancel the dt's.

Comment: My question is why energy is defined as the integral of voltage as a function of charge instead of charge as a function of voltage.

Comment: Sorry for the blunt response. I almost forgot to thank you for responding so quickly! =)

Comment: Oh ok, for that I would more so explain with the concept that voltage is simply a difference in electric potential, which I think more clearly shows that it is dependent on charge; you can change the electric potential difference by changing the charge, rather than the other way around. Honestly though, any way you can find to justify E&M results to understand them is enough of a feat in and of itself. Oh, and no problem, happy to help.

Comment: Mostly because you cannot just have an arbitrary voltage in space without any charge, its (nearly) exactly analogous to gravitational potential energy and mass. A Mass/charge emits a field which then has to be felt by another mass/charge in order to even define work done. Hence the charge and not the voltage is the fundamental object. However you will get a more satisfactory answer on physics stackexchange as this has little to do with math

Comment: Hello Triatticus, Thank you for your explanation and for pointing me to the physics stack exchange. Truth be told, I didn't know it existed.... =I